# Laravel Composer PHP version changed from 5.6 to 7.0.10 gives error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, wamp

I installed my laravel/composer using the PHP version 5.6 and everything was working smoothly now I need to use the LDAP so when I checked and it was given that I need PHP 7.0 or higher to use that so I tried changing the PHP version to 7.0.10 and I am getting following error to the previous code which was working find.

```
QueryException
could not find driver
```

I tried updating the composer but nothing I working fine, any suggestions.

I am using SQL Server, Laravel Framework 5.4.36, PHP 7.0.10.
I need to implement LDAP which is mentioned here so I am making these changes:
https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2-Laravel

The code works fine when I switch back to PHP 5.6 so it seems like there is nothing wrong with the code, My guess is something to do with PHP.
Is there a way to implement LDAP without switching the PHP version.

Comment: That's why homestead or valet are recommended so that you can make environment according to your needs without disturbing other things in the OS. 
Anyhow, If you have tried updating composer then try to update your project also using composer. And clear compiled and cached files.

Comment: @AfrazAhmad Is there any command to update the Laravel Project?

Comment: Yes.but that's not simple as you think because you will have to make changes according to laravel documentation. To update laravel use `composer update in your project directory`. It will update all packages to the latest versions.

Comment: @AfrazAhmad Ran the command `composer update` in my project folder. After that closed all the CMD and opened fresh one from my Project folder to confirm if the query is working fine. Its still not working getting the same `QueryException
could not find driver` error.
Is there anything else I can do to correct it? It is working perfectly with PHP 5.6.

Comment: Try using other version of adldap which is compatible with your php version

Comment: @AfrazAhmad I tried looking but could not find anything.

Comment: Other option is to fix the bug related to driver. search here I hope you will find solution.

Comment: @AfrazAhmad In order to fix the bug only I posted this thread :P 
I was not able to find anything so I thought I will find something by posting.

Comment: Did you tried installing comparability drivers for new php version?? Sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql

Comment: @SyedFaisal Yes I tried this but it gives me error in Windows 10 Command line `Sudo is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file`. Also, I am using the MS SQL Server not MySQL.

Comment: Oh you are using windows 10, your issue is with pdo driver compatibility with database server and php

Comment: @SyedFaisal so what should I do for that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the correct driver for php7.0. If you look run

```
php -m
```

while using php7.0, you will see that you do not have a database driver module installed. Switch back to php5.6 and run the same command. Note all the modules that are installed and then switch back to php7.0 and get all the appropriate modules out of the php7.0 repo.

php5.6 modules will not run (or will rarely run correctly) after you upgrade to php7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot everyone for helping, I finally did it. I was able to change the PHP from PHP 5.6 to 7.0.1 so Now my COMPOSER for LARAVEL is using this.

1. Download and install ODBC drivers here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=36434
2. Download the DLL here (both 7.0. and 7.1.can be found): https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases

Place these DLL Files in your WAMP PHP version folder

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.0.10\ext
```

Open your "php.ini" file and look for the "extension=" line. This will tell you where to put the DDL files. You can put entire path for the DLL like

```
extension=C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.0.10\ext\php_sqlsrv_7_ts.dll
extension=C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.0.10\ext\php_sqlsrv_7_nts.dll
```

Put the DLL files contains in the Zip archive in your extension directory. Make sure to select the proper select the proper version. Note: I initially tried to use the x64 version, but it didn't work. Then, I replaced the DLL with the x86 version and it finally worked.

Posting this answer so that it will help anyone who is struggling just like me.

Make sure to restart your WAMP server.